# Modx moving over to another host stopped admin working

Tags: modx-revolution

I built my site using modx on my test site and then moved it over to my live site, but when I navigated to xxx.com/manager it just displayed my websites home page as if it had found a non-existant page.

Can you tell me what setting I may have missed please?

Comment: Have you set up the database? Are the database-host, user and password all correct?

Comment: Also, please notice that some hosters will prefix your usernames, so maybe you will need to update that information.

Answer (score 0):

You should also run the setup program again.

Also, the docs would help you: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Moving+Your+Site+to+a+New+Server